# Using a query to loop through tables that are similar in structure but have different names

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I would like to use  a query to loop through tables that are similar in structure but have different names  (ie. tableJan2011, tableFeb2011, tableMar2011  etc.)

Is there a way in MS Access and in SQL Server to use the same query statement while varying the table name within it. (similar to using parameter values)  (need this to add different input to each different month's table)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad table design.  You should have a singe table, where you have a column(s) to indicate month/year. You would then just query this single table and add a WHERE month='X' and YEAR='Y' to limit your results to what you need.

without a table redesign use UNION and clever WHERE clause parameters, which will cause rows to only come from the table that applies.

```
SELECT
   ..
    FROM  tableJan2011
    where...
UNION
SELECT
   ..
    FROM  tableFeb2011
    where...
UNION
SELECT
   ..
    FROM  tableMar2011
    where...
```

Comment: Want to use different table tames for the start and end each time it is run therefore i need the table bames not to be hard coded.  Also each table has many fields and if I used one table it would quickly get too large when querying over many years

Comment: @UAB, consider the following. your database will contain all the data regardless of how you split it up into different tables. What you need is a way to quickly find what you are looking for, that is an index [Create and use an index to improve performance](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010210347.aspx). By creating an index, you can quikly get the data you need, and still keep it stored in a single table.  Your life will be 1000 times better once your data is in a single table.

Answer (score 1):

consider moving the year and month out of the table name and into columns in one table.

you can create a table with query or table names to use at runtime, but you have to be able to write Access BASIC code in a module.

Here's an example, assuming you have a query built on a table with the query names you want to execute:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsPTAppend = db.OpenRecordset("qry_PTAppend")
rsPTAppend.MoveFirst
Do Until rsPTAppend.EOF
    qryPT = rsPTAppend("PT")
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs(qryPT)
    sqlOld = qdef.sql
    sqlNew = sqlOld
    ' manipulate sql
    If sqlNew <> sqlOld Then
        qdef.sql = sqlNew
    End If
    db.QueryDefs(rsPTAppend("append")).Execute
    If sqlNew <> sqlOld Then
        qdef.sql = sqlOld
    End If

    rsPTAppend.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, **listen to the people who are telling you to use one table**. They know of which they speak.

If you can't do that for some obscure reason (such as inheriting the design & not being allowed to change it), then you're stuck writing VBA code. There's no way that I know of, in Access, to substitute source tables (or even source columns--values only), in a saved QueryDef.

You'll need something like this:

```
Private Function QueryTable (strTableName as String) As DAO.Recordset

Const theQuery as String = "SELECT tbl.* FROM [table] As tbl"

Dim sSql As String

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    sSql = Replace(theQuery, "[table]", strTableName)

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSql)

    Set QueryTable = rs

End Function
```

Note that this is *simplified* code. There's no error handling, I haven't released the objects (which I usually do, even though they'll go out of scope), and `SELECT *` is almost always a bad idea.

You'd then call this function wherever you need it, passing in the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is possible in Access but in SQL Server you could create a view that use union to get all tables together and then build your queries against the view.

One other option you have could be to build your queries [dynamically](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you can execute a string as sql.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx

I'm not aware of anything similar in MS Access (though my experience is limited). You could however dynamically generate your sql in code to accomplish this. Perhaps you could create a function to take the table suffix and parameters and build the desired sql that way.

Comment: How, exactly, is this helpful? Access/Jet/ACE does not have procedural code in procedures, so there's no way it could provide the same functionality that SQL Server does here. Access does, however, provide VBA where you can write procedural code to do the job. Others have already provided that answer, so I don't really see what this one contributes to the discussion at all. Perhaps you can explain what it adds.